# Django Model not saving.. Totally confused here

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following code in my view

```
page = get_object_or_404(Page, site = site, slug = slug)
pagecontents = PageContent.objects.filter(page=page)
pagecontents[0].description = form.cleaned_data['description']
pagecontents[0].save()
print pagecontents[0].description
print form.cleaned_data['description']
```

When the two print statements execute, i get the following

for the line `print pagecontents[0].description`

```
<p>Most important page</p>
```

for the line `form.cleaned_data['description']`

```
<p>Least important page</p>
```

Why is the object not getting saved?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're not keeping the changed object.

```
pagecontents[0].description = form.cleaned_data['description']
```

This makes an object from `pagecontents[0]`, changes `description`, and then loses track of the object, which gets garbage collected at some point.

```
pagecontents[0].save()
```

This makes another object from `pagecontents[0]` and saves it, which does nothing since it is unchanged.

`pagecontents` is a queryset, so it's not going to create *any* objects until it actually runs the query, which in this case is when you apply `[0]` to it.

You need to keep track of the object:

```
pagecontent = PageContent.objects.filter(page=page)[0]
pagecontent.description = form.cleaned_data['description']
pagecontent.save()
```

Comment: That was it. The perils of coding with little sleep, makes you oversee something so clear as this.

Comment: Can anyone explain this further? why does `pagecontents[0].description` make an object that gets lost but `pagecontent = PageContent.objects.filter(page=page)[0]` and `pagecontent.description = form.cleaned_data['description']` doesn't? To me these look like the same thing.

Comment: Because `pagecontents[0]` is not a variable. It's a temporary value that is the result of the `[]` (`__getitem__`) operation, and once the line ends the reference to that object is lost. So you have to put that reference in a variable for it to persist. -- Put another way, the `pagecontents[0]` in `pagecontents[0].save()` fetches a new copy of the object from `pagecontents`, which does nothing when `save` is called because it's unaltered.